# JIRA Locked after restarts on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, jira, remote-desktop

Im currently running JIRA 6.3.8 on a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine ,which periodically restarts outside of business hours to apply updates.

The result of this is that after every restart, JIRA breaks, stating that the home directory is locked, and a number of plugins fail to load. This has been a recurring problem that I have attempted a number of solutions for, including increasing JVM memory, deleting bundled plugins, creating exceptions in the firewall  and ultimately, reinstalling JIRA(Which doesn't always solve the problem).

Are there any more permenant solutions to this?

EDIT: after some investigation It seems that this is a common problem with seemingly no concrete solution. According to some users, Virtual machines shut down faster and this is causing issues as JIRA doesn't shut down properly, causing these errors

Based off of some comments made, I am unable to install JIRA onto a Linux/Unix VM as It is an enterprise environment and I am only allocated a Windows VM, and disabling automatic updates is not an option due to securty policies regarding the VMs

Comment: I advise you to install JIRA under linux. In case you do not have linux experience, first time it can take you some time, but effort is worth it. I run JIRA 5.2 for 3 years without any problems or break downs.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have access to a Windows environment, My company Doesn't use Linux, or at least wouldn't give me a Linux VM to install it on

Comment: Maybe you can disable automatic updates or automatic restart after updates.

Comment: I tried that route but unfortunately security policy states that updates cannot be disabled. Adding this to the question. Also, do you mean disable automatic restart of the VM after updates or of JIRA?

Comment: I mean tune windows to do not restart after updates installation. I googled this: http://serverfault.com/questions/63779/prevent-server-restart-after-windows-updates
Also I see that the same can be done by editing the registry: http://www.faqforge.com/tag/noautorebootwithloggedonusers/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem several years ago. as I remember, the reason was in JIRA lock file. To solve the problem delete it before start service JIRA again.
The file should be named similar to

`.jira-home.lock`

**EDIT**

forgot to notice, this file is normally hidden

Comment: Thanks for the reply, THe thing is the lock file will disappear after i shutdown jira, so it can still shut down successfully, and when i try to delete the lock file while jira is running it throws a dialog saying cannot delete as its being used by a program(jira). I think i may end up reinstalling jira and importing the backups but I was just wondering if there is some sort of fix i can put in to ensure proper JIRA shutdown before the VM restarts; sometimes it will restart after business hours(9-5) so i cant always be around to shut it down properly

Comment: Are you got the error in case of proper shutdown?
I suppose this file automatically deleted in case of proper JIRA shutdown, but In case of improper shutdown, I guess, it will be remain and you will get lock error

Answer (score 0):

If using ec2 Linux AMI Do the following

1. SSH to machine
2. cd /data/jira  - this is where the lock file is generated when Jira is started
3. ls -la -- Shows all files even hidden ones you can also use ls -al
4. remove .(*).lock file - Delete the lock file
5. Restart jira (/opt/jiraXXX/bin/shutdown.sh followed by startup.sh)
6. Verify the link - JIRA server link
7. If fails with felix cache issue - 
        cd to /data/jira/plugins/.osgi-plugins/felix
8. Delete/remove all the folders in the above folder (sudo rm -rf *)
9. Repeat 5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was caused by a bad symbolic link in jira-shared-data/data